# vb .net project issue

Tags: vb.net

I have a vb.net project with many subfolders. One of them is called "photos". now in my .master page, i have made the background for all other pages. so when the .aspx pages load from one of the sub folders, i give path in .aspx as "../photos/img1.jpg". this all works fine. btw my .master page is in root folder. now i have to call the same images to 2 .aspx pages that are in the root folder so the "../photos/img1.jpg" will not work cause it needs to be "/photos/img1.jpg" 
how do i access the same photo image from different locations with re-copying it again?
i hope u understand my problem and i have explained it clearly. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

~/../Photos/img1.jpg

or

../../Photos/img1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "~" in the path to denote the root directory of the application, rather than using relative paths from your current location.

~/photos/img1.jpg

Here's some more detailed info:  http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/132081.aspx

Comment: did that. it doesnt pick it up. 
my situation is -
Root --> folder1 --> a1.aspx
Root --> photos --> img1.jpg
Root --> a2.aspx
Root --> master1.master (this is where i give the "~/photos" or "../Photos"